# GraphView, как указать время и дату

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, android-fragment

Есть JSON-Массив фаил, каждый блок которого формируется раз в 10 минут, в блоке есть поле-"юникс время дата" и поле-"значение" вот пример -

```
[{"date":1530814200,"value":612},
{"date":1530813600,"value":748},
{"date":1530813000,"value":816},....}]
```

В блоке, первое значение это время сейчас, во втором блоке это минус 10 минут и так далее...
Хочу сделать График, пробую на базе GraphView. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно такое реализовать?
Также прошу подсказать как можно маштабировать график,- 1 час, 3 часа, 6 часов, 12 часов, 24 часа.